# Can't add array of enums to Collection

Tags: java, arrays, collections, enums

This code doesn't work;

```
    ArrayList<BlockFace> cardinalDirections = new ArrayList<>();
    cardinalDirections.addAll(new BlockFace[] {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.WEST});
```

And neither does this;

```
ArrayList<BlockFace> cardinalDirections = Arrays.asList(new BlockFace[] {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.WEST});
```

It only works if I add each element manually one at a time, or iterate through the array;

```
    ArrayList<BlockFace> cardinalDirections = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BlockFace face : new BlockFace[] {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.WEST})
        cardinalDirections.add(face);
```

Why don't the top two examples work?

Comment: `List<BlockFace> cardinalDirections = Arrays.asList(new BlockFace[] {BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.SOUTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.WEST});` instead of `ArrayList<BlockFace>`

Comment: `addAll` doesn't have an overload that accepts an array.

Comment: And `Arrays.asList` has a return type of `List`.

Comment: Don't use a List or ArrayList for holding enum values.  Use [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).  In your case, `EnumSet.allOf(BlockFace.class)` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. BlockFace actually has many more values than listed above, and I only intend to use the ones listed there.

Comment: Post an answer so I can check this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach does not work because `ArrayList.addAll` takes Collection not an array.

Converting enum to ArrayList

```
List<BlockFace> list = Arrays.asList(BlockFace.values());
```